# Powering several amplifiers with one power supply

Tags: power, amplifier

I need to power 5 industrial amplifiers for a project but I am not sure I can use one power supply for all. Here is the amplifier model I will use:
http://www.hbm.com.pl/pdf/a0114.pdf

And manual says "Supply voltage 15 ... 30 V DC (unregulated)" I also didn't get this. Does it mean I don't need a regualted input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a common power supply for all five amplifiers. The supply must be capable of providing enough current for the peak demand of all five amplifiers at once (e.g., 5 × 125 mA = 625 mA). For example, the NT101A/NT102A power supply shown in the datasheet has a rating of 650 mA, which would be plenty.

And yes, it does not need to be a regulated supply, as long as it always produces a voltage in the specified range.

Comment: is that because current draw will not be too much?